# Prevent "Share a link" popup on downvote

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, publicity-badges, share-this

I just downvoted a question on Programmers and got the `share a link to this hot question to earn the publicist badge` popup.  It seems to me that a user will not be likely to link to a question (s)he just downvoted.  Maybe this popup should not be displayed for downvotes?

Comment: What if you want to share it because you want everyone to see how dumb it is?

Comment: Ugh, how pushy.  Not well thought through either, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How dare you down vote something? :)

Good point, this'll be pushed in the next deploy.